# Al ejecutar npm i express, aparece el error ENOTDIR: not a directory

Tags: nodejs, express

Al querer instalar express me presenta el siguiente error:

> $ npm i express
> npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
> npm ERR! path D:\Mi unidad\UDE\Digital House\FullStack\server\node_modules
> npm ERR! errno -4052
> npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'D:\Mi unidad\UDE\Digital House\FullStack\server\node_modules'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\night\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-26T22_51_31_031Z-debug-0.log

Aclaro que previamente ejecuté `npm init`.

Comment: Tenía el mismo error y he cambiado las carpetas a mi disco local y se ha solucionado.

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontre el error, pero lo comparto por si a alguien le sirve, la carpeta del proyecto la tenia en mi google drive, y se ve que tenia algun problema para acceder a crear la carpeta node_modules, movi el proyecto a mi disco c y se ejecuto sin dificultades

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Lee [answer], [ask], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Perdi 3 dias en esto, y como la copia al disco de google drive fue hace 3 semanas, no  estaba percatado de los últimos cambios, en mi disco local funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

me sucedió exactamente lo mismo porque yo también lo ejecuté en Google Drive. Ahora que lo hice en C: funciona bien. Sin embargo, mi intento de hacerlo en Google Drive es para seguir trabajando desde otra computadora, pregunta, se puede instalar en C: y copiar/mover las carpetas a Google Drive y que funcione como si de origen lo hubiera instalado en Google Drive? Gracias

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.